# AS3: Handle BulkLoader.COMPLETE event on AS3 Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events, bulkloader

I am trying to use BulkLoader (https://github.com/arthur-debert/BulkLoader) to preload all assets of my AS3/Flex application. Right now it is working and I am able to access the contents everywhere on my Main module (where my BulkLoader instance lives).

My problem: I need to handle the BulkLoader.COMPLETE event from my preloader (pre.as living next to Main.mxml on src/), to allow the user to exit the preloader and enter the application ONLY after BulkLoader.COMPLETE was fired.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the reference to the BulkLoader instance?

Somethinglike this:

```
preloader.setLoader(_bulkLoaderInstance or name)
```

or

```
var preloader:Preloader = new Preloder(_bulkLoaderInstance or name)
```

BTW, the **LoaderMax** from [Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/) is better (fewer bugs, more reliable events, nicer API).